# Double and triple sum into integral with density of states

Tags: integration, dirac-delta-distributions, discrete, density-of-states

I asked this on mathematical forum section.

I'm triying to expand the results of certain calculation, where the author has the following kind of sums:
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j),
$$
where $A$ and $n$ are analytic functions of the discrete variable $\omega_j$, and all the sums run from $0$ to $\infty$. Now, the author argues that he can passes from the discrete form to a continuum one by defining a density of states $g(\omega)$, so that
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\to\int_0^\infty d\omega g(\omega)A(\omega)n(\omega),
$$
which is usual in this kind of calculations.

Now, in my expressions, I have the following kind of sums:

(i)
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r\neq j}\omega_r n(\omega_r),
$$
and

(ii)
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r\neq j}\omega_r n(\omega_r)\sum_{s\neq j,s\neq r}\omega_s n(\omega_s),
$$
How can I convert them into a integral form?

I was wondering if it has relation with the Kronecker delta, for example, for (i):
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r\neq j}\omega_r n(\omega_r)=\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r}\omega_r n(\omega_r)(1-\delta_{rj})\\
?\to\int d\omega g(\omega)A(\omega)n(\omega)\int d\omega'g(\omega')\omega'n(\omega')\left[1-\delta(\omega'-\omega)\right]
$$
and for (ii)
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r\neq j}\omega_r n(\omega_r)\sum_{s\neq j,s\neq r}\omega_s n(\omega_s)=\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r}\omega_r n(\omega_r)(1-\delta_{rj})\sum_{s}\omega_s n(\omega_s)(1-\delta_{sr})(1-\delta_{sj})\\
?\to\int d\omega g(\omega)A(\omega)n(\omega)\int d\omega'g(\omega')\omega'n(\omega')\left[1-\delta(\omega'-\omega)\right]\int d\omega''g(\omega'')\omega''n(\omega'')\left[1-\delta(\omega''-\omega')\right]\left[1-\delta(\omega''-\omega)\right]
$$

The above looks wrong for me, because I will have expressions like
$$
\int d\omega d\omega'd\omega'' F(\omega)G(\omega')H(\omega'')\delta(\omega'-\omega)\delta(\omega''-\omega')\delta(\omega''-\omega)\\
=\delta(0)\int d\omega d\omega'F(\omega)G(\omega')H(\omega')\delta(\omega'-\omega)\\
=\delta(0)\int d\omega F(\omega)G(\omega)H(\omega),
$$
then, the presence of $\delta(0)$ implies a infinity.

Another way that I explored is to complete the summation, I mean, for (i):
$$
\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r\neq j}\omega_r n(\omega_r)=\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) n(\omega_j)\sum_{r}\omega_r n(\omega_r)-\sum_{j} A(\omega_j) \omega_j n^2(\omega_j),
$$
where the second term is easy to transform into an integral form, but I have not idea how to transform the first one, given the double sum involved.

**Edited:** From the last one expression, given that the sums are independent, I think that the correct pass to the continuum is
$$
\int d\omega g(\omega)A(\omega)n(\omega)\int d\omega' g(\omega')\omega'n(\omega')-\int d\omega g(\omega)A(\omega)\omega n^2(\omega)
$$

I will be thankful if you can give me some solution or advice to this problem.